# how to check if a float value is greater than another float value in python?

Tags: python

I have to check if the input value is greater than 0.00125 in python.
The code is

```
if float(line) > 0.00125
```

It is not checking the value. Is there any other keyword for doing this?

Comment: I suggest you manually inspect the value of `line`, because the `>` operator works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean 'not checking'? What is output?

Comment: I bet you `line` contains extraneous characters and leading or trailing whitespace (space, newline). Use  `(string.strip(line))` and/or `line.split()[...]`

Comment: Make sure your input value is not a string but an integer.

Comment: Or a floating-point number.

Comment: surely this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `raw_input` for getting the user input? This works perfect.

```
line = raw_input("Type a float: ")
if (float(line) > 0.00125):
    print "input is bigger"
else:
    print "input is lower"
```

Comment: This shouldn't have any effect, as `float()` can handle a string (as from `raw_input()`) just as easily as a `float()` (as from `input()`). We don't know if the OP is using Python 2 or 3, anyway - the question doesn't really tell us much at all.

Comment: `line` may even have come from an external source like a file.

Comment: given how poorly the question is stated, this answer is *very* premature.  why did you add parentheses and a space between `float` and `(line)` in your `if` statement?  surely you don't think those changes are meaningful.